# Calculating odds ratio for quasibinomial glm

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, odds-ratio, quasi-likelihood

I have a quasibinomial glm and I'd like to get odds ratios for each of the predictors. Is it acceptable to use the 'oddsratio' package in R in the same method that you would for a binomial model (e.g. https://pat-s.github.io/post/oddsratio/)?

If not, is there a better approach to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the odds ratio from the exponential of the coefficients given from the glm, so you'd have:

```
model1 <- x ~ y, data = data, family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit')
exp(coef(model1))
```